# Determine number of factors of a given number without overlap in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data set with orders of tickets. Tickets can be bought in packs of 5, or 3, as well as individually. I need to group the data using the quantity of tickets sold per order, to determine if it was a 5 pack (divisible by five), then 3 pack, or else/then individually (1 or 2 qty). So if I have a quantity of 27, I know that order consisted of five "5 packs", and 2 individual tickets.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN (id % 5) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) fivepack
```

I have this in my query, but stringing these together for fivepack, and threepack, doesn't eliminate the starting number from the total quantity on the next operation. So a quantity of 27, would yield a result of 5 "five packs" and 9 "three packs", and then 27 "individuals".

So given a quantity, how would you first divide by a large factor, get the remainder and divide by the smaller, then finally handle the remainder?

Edit:

The sample packs provide a discount of the purchase price(not relevant to the technical issue), so the first maximum division needs to occur first. So as Gordon Linoff asked below, in the case of 27 tickets quantity, you would take the maximum number of 5 divisions first, then pass the remainder to try to divide by 3, and then return the final remainder as individuals.

The issue is passing the value of one operation in SQL to the next operation, so so on. So I can do Math1, pass Answer1 to Math2, and then pass Answer2 to Math3.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results, so others can make sense of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't fully understand why 27 would be 5 five packs and 2 individuals rather than any of the following:

- 27 individuals
- 9 3-packs
- 4 5-packs, 2 3-packs, 1-individual
- 8 3-packs and 3 individuals
- and so on.

But, if you want a greedy approach, you can use the following arithmetic:

```
select floor(num / 5) as five_packs,
       floor( (num - 5 * floor(num / 5)) / 3) as three_packs,
       num - 5 * floor(num / 5) - 3 * floor( (num - 5 * floor(num / 5)) / 3) as singles
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/30136) is a SQL Fiddle illustrating the logic.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I answered your question above, but the packs are a pricing discount. Thank you for your solution. It looks like it will work!